# Mongoose.js - TypeError: Model.deleteOne is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, typeerror

I am new to node.js, hence a very trivial question.

I have the following lines of code:

(A) Defined a model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Perform model delete operation

```
module.exports.deleteGenre = function (id, callback) {
  console.log("Deleting genre: "+ id);
  var condition = {"_id": id};
  Genre.deleteOne(condition, callback);
};
```

I have referred to the following [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteOne) on the function.

However, when I run it, it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Genre.deleteOne is not a function
```

If I replace the deleteOne() function with remove(), the code works. 
Please advise, where am I going wrong.

Comment: If the remove() function works its ok with using it since your filter is the objectId ( which is a unique ID)

Comment: How do you access Genre? Try creating a model from your schema: 
let GenreModel = mongoose.model('genre', GenreSchema);

and then call Genre.deleteOne()

Comment: It seems they removed this function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

as user3344977 said in comment, the function `deleteOne` and `deleteMany` no longer exist in mongoose 4. the API documentation is not up to date.

I just checked the source code of mongoose (4.4) and there is no a single trace of these function.

you can use `Model.findOneAndRemove(condition, options, callback)` or `Model.findByIdAndRemove(id, options, callback)` instead.