# Mongoose deleteOne, findOneAndDelete, findOneAndRemove not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I tried the following code (other similar functions as well) and it did work initially but did not work later. There is a item with matching id and this did not give any error and executes but the document is not removed from MongoDB

```js
CompanyModel.findOneAndDelete({ id: data.id }, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide at least one record from your DB with id in place?

Comment: If there really is a matching entry that will work, so the most likely explanation is that either you aren't performing the search you think you are or that there actually is no matching entry. Does `findOne()` return a value for the same search object? Is there some other async event happening that's confusing the issue?

Comment: I found the issue. It was due to unavailability of the document as it is created just after the deletion as I used model.save inside process.nextTick function.

Answer (score 1):

the mongo id is `_id` and the comparison value should be transformed into ObjectId :

```
// import { ObjectId } from 'bson';

{_id: new ObjectId(id)}
```

if you don't want to work with `_id` you have to make sure that the id field exists and that it contains the value (with the right type). The request seems to be good otherwise.

Comment: I think no need to transform into `ObjectId`. It should work with `data.id`.

Comment: yep id field has the correct value and even if I hard-code it, result is same. It worked initially and later it failed.

Comment: @DuminduDharmawardhana does a query directly on the database work? (for example : `doc.find({ 'id' : 'someValue' })` )

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide _id: data.id in filter.
Ex.

```
CompanyModel.findOneAndDelete({ _id: data.id }, function (err, doc) { 
    //code here 
}
```

Comment: What I want is to filter by id field not _id

Answer (score 0):

I found it in a bit after publishing the question. Issue is that, I was running a test where creating document and deleting it happened one after another in my socket-io client but I have used "process.nextTick" function in saving the model in server side but not for the delete. So the delete happened just before the creation. I expected this situation to give an error but it does not give any error if an item is not found.

I was confused as I found Model.deleteOne is not supported anymore [Mongoose.js - TypeError: Model.deleteOne is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798869/mongoose-js-typeerror-model-deleteone-is-not-a-function)